# Is there anywhere else to catch exceptions?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, exception, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor (server) app, I have a try/catch in pretty much every method called by the framework. I don't if a method is say setting a bool to true (OnChanged method), but everything else.

I also have `<ErrorBoundary>` surrounding everything in MainLayout.razor (see below).
Does this mean I will catch any exception thrown anywhere anyhow? Or is there somewhere/something else I need to do to capture another set of exceptions?

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div style="margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        <header>
                            <Banner ShowBanner="@SessionData.ShowWelcomeBanner"
                                    OnBannerClosed="WelcomeBannerClosed"
                                    BannerContent="Please complete your registration. <a href='/Account/Welcome'>Click here for more information.</a>" />
                        </header>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        <NavMenu />
                    </div>
                    <div style="flex-grow: 1; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                        <div style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                            <main>
                                <div class="my-main-scrollbar">
                                    <PopupMessageBox>
                                        @Body
                                    </PopupMessageBox>
                                </div>
                            </main>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        <footer class="main-footer">
                            <span>&copy; David Thielen 2023 - ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent Context="error">
        @{
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var useFallback = true;
            if (error.Data.Contains("Category"))
            {
                var data = error.Data["Category"];
                if (data is Type category)
                {
                    var logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(category);
                    logger.LogError(error, "Error: {guid}", guid);
                    useFallback = false;
                }
            }
            if (useFallback)
            {
                Logger.LogError(error, "Error: {guid}", guid);
            }
        }

        <h1>Unexpected Error (sorry)</h1>

        <p>
            The program has encountered an unexpected error (yes there are expected errors). This error has been
            logged and we will look at it.
        </p>

        <p>We suggest you <a href="/identity/account/LogOut">logout</a> and then log back in if you wish to try again.</p>

        <p>If you want to contact us, please include the following error id: @guid when you do.</p>

    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Comment: Well, yes using [`Error boundaries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#error-boundaries) you can capture all the errors globally. `Error boundaries` would renders error UI when any unhandled exception is thrown throughout the application. However, you can also use [`Problem details`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#problem-details) middleware within program.cs file.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron thank you. Can you write this up as an answer and I'll select it. And I suggest in the answer you keep it simple. Reading that link you can get really fancy with using this, but for most developers, like me, all we need at first is just the exception written to the log with a notification to the user. And hopefully it happens so rarely, that's all we'll ever need. TIA

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, I tried to explain it according to your explanation. Thanks once again.

Comment: I would remove almost all of the `try`/`catch` code you have unless you know that there are ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle. You should code to avoid exceptions in the first place. Exceptions should be for exceptional circumstances and not a standard way of programming. You should read Eric Lippert's blog on the four types of exceptions: https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @Enigmativity Mostly I log the exception and then call `throw;` There are some cases where I can act on them.

Comment: Calling `throw` loses all of your call stack on the previous exception. Logging is not a good reason to do exception handling on each block of code. Have you tried `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I think that's incorrect. Calling `throw e;` loses the call stack. But calling `throw;` preserves it.

Comment: @DavidThielen - You are correct. My mistake. I do try to code to avoid exceptions where possible so I don't often need to `throw`.

Comment: @Enigmativity No problem, there's too much to keep track of everything. BTW, another thing I do in the catch is `ex.Data.Add("Category", typeof(OrganizationProfile));` and I then log in the catch doing the work that category. Makes it easier to filter by the first touch category as the log is in another class.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It's on my list but I had a couple of other features that were moved ahead of this. thanks

Comment: Okay, sure,  I got it, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apart from [error boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#error-boundaries) , you use [problem details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#problem-details) extentison method, which will bind the responses for all HTTP client and server errors. Problem details which actually implements [IProblemDetailsService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iproblemdetailsservice?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that helps keeping your errors within asp.net core app. This extension method is pretty straight forward in terms of its implementation. You can simply include following line:

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
```

**Note:** Microsoft doesn't recommned to expose error details other than development environment due to the security risk.

[image]

**Can be customize:**

Problme details extension method is an automatic error writer, which can be customized the response by using [CustomizeProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#customize-problem-details) and your modification can be applied to all auto-generated problem details. You can do as following:

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(options =>
    options.CustomizeProblemDetails = ctx =>
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Extensions.Add("nodeId", Environment.MachineName));
```

In addition, `ProblemDetails.Extensions` is a `IDictionary` type which contains `IDictionary<string, object?>`, so any additional information can be passed here.

[image]

**Note:** Please be informed that, while using a custom IProblemDetailsWriter, the custom IProblemDetailsWriter must be registered before calling AddRazorPages, AddControllers, AddControllersWithViews, or AddMvc. [Please refer to this official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#custom-iproblemdetailswriter)